# Multi Product Linear Programming Optimization with Pulp

Tags: python, optimization, linear-programming, pulp, maximize

I have a Multiple production LP optimization problem in which the product(B1,B2,D) will be received in variable quantity with respect to date column, the Optimizer should give the Min_Capacity Max_Capacity to be planned on every day
LP variable are Assy Out B1 , Assy Out B2 , Assy Out D , Open Assy Line(Binary decision to produce or not in given date)
The target to maximize the assembly output per day and the constraints are material receipt for each date and not allowed to produce more than material available in each date
Tried the problem in Excel its working fine but unable to fix the model in Pulp , as my real data have more than 200 variable which is not feasible in excel sheet

[image]

```
x=np.arange(1,10)

Assy_B1=pulp.LpVariable.dicts('Assy_B1',x,0,None,'Integer')

Assy_B2=pulp.LpVariable.dicts('Assy_B2',x,0,None,'Integer')
Assy_D=pulp.LpVariable.dicts('Assy_D',x,0,None,'Integer')
Open_Line=pulp.LpVariable.dicts('Open_Line',x,0,None,'Binary')
model=LpProblem('Assembly_Plan',LpMaximize)

model +=lpSum([ Assy_B1[t] + Assy_B2[t] + Assy_D[t] for t in x])

for i in x:
    model+=(Assy_B1[i]+Assy_B2[i]+Assy_D[i])<=dfs.loc[i,'Max_Capacity ']*Open_Line[i])

model.solve()

 Status Optimal
```

[image]

Comment: You may want to show your Python code and tell us where you got stuck.

Comment: I have added the code and result data with Assy_Out B1, B2 and D as per the model, but the issue is Assy Out D is 100 for  Date 1 where as the input D is 0, similarly Assy Out B2 for Date 2 is 100 but the input till that date is only 30 , so the model is filling irrespective of date wise available of material , need to restrict the same and Assy out should not exceed the received material with respect to date

Comment: The model output results are in the last 3 columns

Comment: See: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: sorry new to stack overflow and coding itself , hope to explain better next